# Why doesn't Ubuntu Server detect my drive (while Ubuntu Desktop does)?

Tags: server, usb, 22.04, filesystem

When I plug in my USB on my laptop with a freshly installed Ubuntu Server I
get [such message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257270/get-rid-of-no-caching-mode-page-found-message-during-boot).

```
[43857.642914] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[43857.643557] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb-drive
does not give me any output. The drive seems to be mounted as confirmed by `lsblk`
showing that it is mounted in /media/usb-drive. The issue is that there seems to be no data in it.

`df -hT` on my other PC, with Ubuntu Desktop LTS installed, shows:

```
/dev/sda1                 ext4    29G   24K   27G   1% /media/jim/bb4bb2b2-21ca-4003-b128-605c2bcb9c37
```

And when I access the drive from my Ubuntu Desktop I can find data there.
This is not the case when I try to accass the data from Ubuntu Server - there is nothing.
I checked the drive with `badblocks` but no damage was found:

```
Checking blocks 0 to 30253055
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

**1.** Why cannot I access my drive from Ubuntu Server whereas I can from Ubuntu Desktop?

**2.** What might be the reason and the significance of the message I'm getting when
plugging in the drive?